# Kentico 9 - How to get assigned role info or name to a document

Tags: kentico

In Kentico 9 application, assigned different role to specific documents, so that only authorized user can have access of that specific document or page.

There is drop down list showing page list, and need to show only those page which have same access role as logged in user have.

Is there in kentico in built macro available to achieve same or what kentico API could be used to get document assigned role in transformation or grammatically?

Comment: Hey, I'm not quite sure what are you trying to get. Could you more elaborate on what exactly would you like to retrieve?

Comment: Hi Enn, appreciate quick reply,

For example I have page (CMS.MenuItem), in security tab I have add role "XYZ" to that document. In my front end used a repeater to display list of pages, now I want to display on those pages in that list which have same assigned role as current logged in user have, other page should not display in list which don't have same role as user. 

Hope now I am clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using some viewer web part, like repeater, there is a checkbox in web part settings saying check permissions - this will return only documents current user can see.

If you're pulling documents in code behind use document query CheckPermissions method like this:

```
 DocumentHelper.GetDocuments()
            .Published()
            .Where(where)
            .CheckPermissions();
```